Symfony 6 add a prefix to database tables without changing entity names
I'm asking how I could have a table prefix in symfony 6.
I would like to keep my entity names like "User", "Product", "Command", ..., but in database that shall be in relation with "prefix_users","prefix_products","prefix_commands", ...
I've found an old resource about that for symfony 4, but paths and classes are evolved since that version, and I can't reproduce that thing today. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sk2ghWLjKZQ
I don't see anything in documentation which leads me to think that this is a feature that exists within symfony (and that's a shame).
I know that I could rename all my entities, but that overload the code, and isn't necessary to understand code itself. It may be only a paramter known by config and doctrine... As it is able to retrieve the database table plural name for a entity singular name !
Is there a classical solution to resolve that ?

I've finally found it !
I share my solution just in case others have the same question :
According to this documentation (that I hadn't read before) :

create a "service", to do the modification of table names :


<?php
// Src\Service\DatabaseTablePrefix.php

namespace App\Service;

use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\EventSubscriber\EventSubscriberInterface;
use \Doctrine\ORM\Event\LoadClassMetadataEventArgs;

class DatabaseTablePrefix implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  private $prefix;

  public function __construct($prefix){
    $this->prefix =$prefix;
  }

  public function getSubscribedEvents(){

    return array('loadClassMetadata');

  }

  public function loadClassMetadata(LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $eventArgs)
  {
    $classMetadata = $eventArgs->getClassMetadata();

    if (!$classMetadata->isInheritanceTypeSingleTable() || $classMetadata->getName() === $classMetadata->rootEntityName) {
      $classMetadata->setPrimaryTable([
        'name' => $this->prefix . $classMetadata->getTableName()
      ]);
    }

    foreach ($classMetadata->getAssociationMappings() as $fieldName => $mapping) {
      if ($mapping['type'] == \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata::MANY_TO_MANY && $mapping['isOwningSide']) {
        $mappedTableName = $mapping['joinTable']['name'];
        $classMetadata->associationMappings[$fieldName]['joinTable']['name'] = $this->prefix . $mappedTableName;
      }
    }
  }
}



In /config/services.yaml add this in services part :

// config\services.yaml

{...}

Services
    {...}
    App\Service\DatabaseTablePrefix:
          arguments:
            $prefix: '%env(PREFIXE_DATABASE_TABLE)%'
          tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_suscriber }



And in your .env, add this line :

// .env

PREFIXE_DATABASE_TABLE="prefix_"


You can now drop and recreate your database, and tables.

The only one question I still have is : why the messenger_messages table hasn't the prefix applied too ? It's the only table that doesn't matter about that.
database prefix tables example
